# Issue with base R file.choose() function in Windows 11. File explorer comes up blank, no file names. R version 4.3.0

Tags: r, rstudio, windows-11

Recently some of our users have had a problem with their R scripts that use the file.choose function to open the file explorer. The file explorer opens, but none of the file names or text are visible at all. You can still select files, but you just cannot tell which files you are selecting, or from where.
They are on Windows 11 (up to date), R version is 4.3.0, Rstudio version is 2023.03.0 Build 386.

Let me know if there is any other information I can provide about this, or if there is anything you all have tried that has worked to solve this. Open to any and all suggestions!

[image]

Tried to run the file.choose command from an R script. It used to open file explorer and let you choose the file you needed. It now opens file explorer, but blank with no file names or labels of any kind.

Blank file explorer, highlighted:
[image]

Comment: Maybe use `tcltk::tk_choose.files()` instead.

Comment: Does `choose.files()` work?  It's slightly different than `file.choose()`.  If it looks the same, can you make the names visible by highlighting a range of files?  Your image kind of looks like a display of black lettering on a black background, so highlighting might change things.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! Unfortunately, we are still having the same problem. tcltk::tk_choose.files() - opened the file explorer, but it was still blank. We also tried using choose.files() and it also gives the same blank screen. Ill add an image of the blank file explorer to my original post, as even highlighting the files still does not reveal their names. Even the right click menu shows up blank!

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but I encountered the same issue and using an older version of R solved it (switching from R 4.3 to R 4.2.2)

Comment: Thank you for this tip! Were you also on windows 11 when you encountered the problem? What version of R Studio were you using when you switched from R 4.3 to R 4.2.2? I would love to replicate this solution for now until (hopefully) the next update fixes this problem.